# button situation when switching between user controls at C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

in my program, I have 2 buttons(Start & Stop) in one of my user controls. what I want is that when Start Button is clicked Stop Button should be enabled and the Start button should be disabled. conversely when the Stop button is clicked start button should be enabled and the stop button should be disabled. everything works fine until I switch between user controls. when I click on other user controls and turn back to the main user control the buttons situation turns into the initialize moment

```
        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Some_Function();
            Start.Enabled = false;
            Stop.Enabled = true; 
        }

        private void btnStopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Some_Function();
            Stop.Enabled = false;
            Start.Enabled = true;

        }
```

here is the image of the buttons situation before switching between user controls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAuUL.png)

here is the image of the buttons situation after switching between user controls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJDVU.png)

Comment: This is expected behavior because the UserControl initialize and re-draw again. Are you closing UserControl which they contains these buttons? If no, to handle this you can pass the lastStatus parameter from 2nd UserControl to main user control and set the enabled status of the button on loading action.

Answer (score -1):

As mert said, this is expected behavior.

I just put the Start and Stop Buttons in my main form and pulled them out of my user control. This way, users can see the start and stop buttons from anywhere in my code.

I didn't use the passing data solution. With this solution, we should pass the data between forms which I didn't want to do.